# How to fork n children and have them execute different tasks in C?

Tags: concurrency, fork

I'm trying to create 4 children processes from a parent and have each child execute something different.

```
int main(void) {
int processes = 4;
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= processes; i++) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
}
int status;
for (i = 1; i <= processes; i++)
    wait(&status);
}
```

Right now the output produces
    pid: 5847
    pid: 5846
    pid: 5845
    pid: 5844

Why are the pid's in decreasing rather than increasing orders? Am I not correctly using the fork() to create the children?

Comment: the pids can be in any order - why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an optical illusion. The PIDs are in increasing order ;) Let me explain:

- First, process 5844 is created
- Then process 5845 is created
- Then process 5846 is created
- Then process 5847 is created
- Then process 5847 is selected by the OS scheduler and prints "5847"
- Then process 5846 is selected by the OS scheduler and prints "5846"
- Then process 5845 is selected by the OS scheduler and prints "5845"
- Then process 5844 is selected by the OS scheduler and prints "5844"

You just have no control over which process is selected first by the scheduler. But, if you add a `sleep(1);` to the end of your `for` loop, I'm sure the PIDs will be in increasing order (unless you hit the ceiling and they wrap around.)

At least Linux and OS X produces PIDs in increasing order, don't know about other Unix-like operating systems.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int processes = 4;
    int i;
    int fork_result;
    int number_of_children;
    for (i = 1; i <= processes; i++) {
        fork_result = fork();
        if (fork_result > 0) {
            printf("parent says: hello child #%d, how are you?\n", fork_result);
            number_of_children++;
        } else if (fork_result == 0) {
            printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        } else if (fork_result < 0) {
            printf("parent says: fork() failed\n");
        }
    }
    int status;
    for (i = 1; i <= number_of_children; i++) {
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

On my system (OS X 10.10.5) this prints:

```
parent says: hello child #2577, how are you?
parent says: hello child #2578, how are you?
pid: 2577
pid: 2578
parent says: hello child #2579, how are you?
parent says: hello child #2580, how are you?
pid: 2579
pid: 2580
```

What OS are you using? The "parent says:" lines should be in increasing order in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation on what's happening. That make it's a lot more clear. I'm using Ubuntu and adding in the sleep(1) does allow it to print in increasing order.

Can you possibly explain the final for loop with the wait? It seems to run the sum regardless of whether or not it's there.

Comment: @omgitsbd - with the wait(), the parent process waits for the child processes to finish. if you omit it, the parent process may exit earlier than the child process: this would kill the remaining children and you'd just see part of the childrens output, or no output at all. However, if the children are faster than the parent, you will not be able to observe a difference. Except that you have to take care to not produce too many zombies => but in the example this is not a problem, because the zombies are garbage-collected when the parent exits.